# SQlite between query is not working correctly

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

Creating a desktop application to calculate grades for students so each student scores has a date column so I can calculate the totals between two dates using the calendar from Tkinter.

```
query = "SELECT SUM (scores) 
         FROM sscores 
         WHERE acttype = ? 
         AND sid = ? 
         AND ssub = ? 
         AND sdate BETWEEN '"+ ft1.get() +"' AND '"+ft2.get()+"'"
        
c.execute(query, (sact1, stuid, f1.get()))
```

For some reason it gives no query result when I query before any month of January even though the only scores I have inputed was dated in January.
When I choose a date before the month of January and a date after the month of January, there would be no query result however if I choose a date during the month of January and a date after the month January, it gives me the correct query result. The weird thing is even if I choose a date in January years before it gives me the correct query result but when I choose any month before January, it gives me nothing. From my understanding, choosing a month before January and choosing a month still means the date of the score is in between but it does not result in the correct date.

Comment: Looks like your BETWEEN acts as string-type, not date-type compare. PS. Unrelated tag removed.

Comment: yup, the date is coming out as str instead of date. will have to figure out how I can convert it to date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you could use parameter for all the values and avoid string concatenation to build sql code

```
query = "SELECT SUM (scores) 
             FROM sscores 
             WHERE acttype = ? 
             AND sid = ? 
             AND ssub = ? 
             AND sdate BETWEEN ? AND ? "
    
c.execute(query, (sact1, stuid, f1.get(), ft1.get() , ft2.get()))
```

Anyway be sure for proper matching sequence of values and data type in your execute call and also for a valid content of each var.